# After including Relative layout in the Drawer layout options in the menu don't respond to click

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I created **navigation drawer** across **multiple activities**. In xml I have a *Drawer layout*. Before including relative (or others) layout in it, options in the menu were clickable (going to other activities). However, after including layout, it **stopped going to other activities** (options are not clickable).

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />
        <include
            layout="@layout/main2_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And code for Main2Activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        //here is the main place where we need to work on.
        int id=item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.nav_camera:
                Intent h = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(h);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:
                Intent g = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Settings.class);
                startActivity(g);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_slideshow:
                Intent s = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Allergy2.class);
                startActivity(s);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_manage:
                Intent t = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Instruction.class);
                startActivity(t);
                break;

        }
```

Comment: A drawerlayout is allowed only 2 children, the first is a main content view, the second is the drawer. what is the content of app_bar_main2, and main2_image. Could you please explain what is your goal?

Comment: You meant after adding `layout="@layout/main2_image"`?

Comment: @Mohsen, yes. After adding main2_image layout, the options in the menu stopped to be clickable.

Comment: Probably the `DrawerLayout` cannot recognize that layout. What are the contents of this layout? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mohsen, a new layout has a button and edittext in it. When I didn't use include, but had relative layout inside, the options weren't clickable to

Comment: @Mohsen, can't I use relative layout in main2_image? Why DrawerLayout cannot recognize it? I need button and edittext to be like I putted them in the relative layout, and sliding menu on top of that relative layout.

Comment: Add `CoordinatorLayout` and then inside `NestedScrollView`, your content like `Relativelayout` or just a `Relativelayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using **Fragments** instead of **Activities**!!

To clear out your question you said that you want to switch between multiple activities and these all activities have the same `NavigationDrawer` Layout!

If yes its a very bad practice...you can use Fragments instead of each activity you've created in the NavDrawerMenu... TODO that follow me:

First you will create your **MainActivity** with the Navigation drawer as normal then in the method `onNavigationItemSelected` here you will begin the transactions between the fragments instead of `Intent` as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    //here is the main place where we need to work on.
    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, new 
                                       BlankFragment1()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, new 
                 BlankFragment2()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_slideshow:
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, new 
                  BlankFragment3()).commit();
            break;
    }
```

**NOTE:** you surly know that these fragments must be the child of an activity so `main_frameLayout` is the ***id*** of `FrameLayout` that the fragments are placed in in the activity you placed the NavigationDrawer in which is the MainActivity as follows:

**app_bar_nav_drawer.xml**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.tkmsoft.taahel.activities.MainActivity">

       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_filter_button"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

          </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
               </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Before creation of the menu, I have developed multiple activities. Can I somehow change these activities to fragments without losing their capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening here is that your drawer is shadowed by the additional children you've created in the `DrawerLayout`.

To fix this, in the `onCreate` method of your `Main2Activity`, get a reference to your `NavigationView` and bring it to front:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you added `CoordinatorLayout` and then inside `-> AppBarLayout` as it's child **in `app_bar_main2`** with `Toolbar`, then you better to add your contents inside the `CoordinatorLayout` or maybe inside a `NestedScrollView` which is a child of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

The problem why they're not clickable is that the `DrawerLayout` cannot recognize this layout as it's child:

```
<include
  layout="@layout/main2_image"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

So, put the contents of this layout inside `CoordinatorLayout` and it's child `NestedScrollView`.